# How to output hierarchical list in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hierarchy

I have a hierarchical structure of pages when one page can be a parent of another. Pages are stored in a DB table with the following structure:

- page.id
- page.name
- page.parent_id

Now I need to output them is a hierarchical list like:

- Page A
- - Page B
- - Page C
- - - Page D
- - - etc
- Page E

Also there is no limit to a number of levels.

What would be the best approach to achieve that in RoR? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi i would use some gem to do this

i.e.

https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about this gem. I'm new to Ruby and Rails and don't know all the possible options. Will give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

Here are the best practices to handle - https://blog.francium.tech/best-practices-for-handling-hierarchical-data-structure-in-ruby-on-rails-b5830c5ea64d

A Simple table

```
Table Emp
id: Integer
name: String
parent_id: Integer
```

Associations

```
app/models/emp.rb
class Emp < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :subs, class_name: 'Emp', foreign_key: :parent_id
  belongs_to :superior, class_name: 'Emp', foreign_key: :parent_id
end
```

Scope Definition

```
class Emp < ApplicationRecord
  ----
  ----
  scope :roots, -> { where(parent_id: nil) }
end
```

Fetching data

```
def tree_data
  output = []
  Emp.roots.each do |emp|
    output << data(emp)
  end
  output.to_json
end
def data(employee)
  subordinates = []
  unless employee.subs.blank?
    employee.subs.each do |emp|
      subordinates << data(emp)
    end
  end
  {name: employee.name, subordinates: subordinates}
end
```

Eager Loading

```
def tree_data
  output = []
  Emp.roots.includes(subs: {subs: {subs: subs}}}.each do |emp|
    output << data(emp)
  end
  output.to_json
end
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Thanks. Now its fit in so and helpful to others in case link is not work. Good job :)

Answer (score 1):

As another user suggested, you could use `ancestry` gem but it will require changes to your database. If you can't do that you should create a directed acyclic graph and set depth for each node.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :depth

  def children
    @children ||= []
  end
end

# Loading required pages in single query, add predicate if needed
pages = Page.includes(:parent).all

# Setting up a hash table to find pages in constant time
page_index = pages.reduce({}){|acc, page| acc[page.id] = page}

# Setting up children
pages.each do |page|
  if page.parent_id
    page_index[page.parent_id].children << page
  end
end

# Basic depth-first search routine
def dfs(page, visited, depth)
  page.depth = depth
  visited[page.id] = true
  page.children.select{|p| visited[p] == nil}.each{|p| dfs(p, visited, depth + 1)}
end

# Performing depth-first search for each connected component
visited = {}
pages.each do |page|
  if visited[page.id] == nil
    dfs(page, visited, 0)
  end
end
```

So, now each page has a depth attribute and you can print the list however you like.

Answer (score 0):

Hypothetical code, not verified.

```
class Page < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children, class_name: 'Page', foreign_key: 'parent_id'
  belongs_to :parent, class_name: 'Page'
end

# Helper
def tree_list(collection)
  content_tag :ul do
    collection.each do |item|
      if item.children.blank?
        content_tag :li do
          item.name
        end
      else
        tree_list(item)
      end
    end
  end 
end

# View
tree_list(Page.all)
```

The basic idea is the `tree_list` method will make a recursive list until there is no children for a certain page.

Comment: Thanks, I gave it a try and it worked! Couple of enhancements though: 1) nested content_tag is counter-intuitive. See this link for details: http://robots.thoughtbot.com/nesting-content-tag-in-rails-3; 2) I changed the code a little bit: `def tree_list(collection)
    content_tag(:ul) do
      collection.each do |item|
        concat(content_tag(:li, item.name))
        if !item.children.blank?
          concat(tree_list(item.children))
        end
      end
    end 
  end `
This is a working version.

Comment: Although this approach works I'll most likely stick to using an existing gem in order not to reinvent the wheel. Thanks for your suggestion anyway!

Comment: It depends on use case but not about inventing wheels. If using only one method could solve my problem, I will definitely not go for a gem. That's basic principle of simplicity.